# Getting The connection attempt failed. - code:0 from RDS Proxy

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-rds-proxy

We are using RDS proxy for postgres.

We randomly get `The connection attempt failed. - code:0` error, but not all the time.

The application uses `PGSimpleDataSource`  which doesn't have any connection pool since RDS Proxy handles the connection pool.

Should we use some other Datasource ?